# Unable to access redirectAttributes while redirecting to controller action with Paramerters

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, redirect

In Spring MVC,

When the return value contains `redirect:` prefix, the `viewResolver` recognizes this as a special indication that a redirect is needed. The rest of the view name will be treated as the `redirect URL`. And the client will send a new request to this redirect URL.

We can write a handler method like this to handle the redirect:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public String foo(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)  {
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "I am message");
    return "redirect:/bar";
}
```

Now we can access this redirectAttribute in `bar()` like this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/bar", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public String bar(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model)  {
    String error = (String) model.asMap().get("message");
}
```

Normally we can access this the redirectAttribute inside `bar()` method, But when I specify a URL as parameterised url in return statement like this below

```
return "redirect:/bar?x=1&y=2";
```

I am unable to access the redirectAttributes

I further Inspected network in chrome and I found that while using un-parameterised url in return statement `jsessionid` remains same after redirect, but it does changes while using parameterised urls.

Can anyone please tell me why is this happening or am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: Why don't you try to debug model on bar method in order to get the object you're receiving when using parameterized url?

Comment: it just shows null..everything works fine with un-parameterised url but breaks for parameterised url

Comment: were you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the value of paramater `x` and `y` in your redirect controller you need to get `Parameter` from `request`.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/bar", method = RequestMethod.GET )
  public String bar(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model)  {
      System.out.println(request.getParameter("y"));
      return null;
  }
```

Comment: No, I want to access the value of FlashAttribute error. Clearly mentioned in question 